# How to remove "/?COLLCC=" from WordPress URLs

Tags: wordpress, url

I have noticed on a WordPress Website I am working on that, where with every URL, "/?COLLCC=" is appended. I recently added "Options All -Indexes" to the end of the htaccess of the site to disable Directory Browsing, but am unsure whether this is at all related to the cause of the issue.

I've done some reading, on this site especially, where it has been suggested to add the following code to the htaccess file;

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} collcc=
RewriteRule (.*) http://my-site.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

However, will this pose a problem with speed results since it applies a redirect, and if so, is there any other solution out there?

If you would like anymore details please do tell me -

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you find out what adds that argument.  It's either the theme, or a plugin, that's adding it.  Figure it out, and fix it at the cuase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you can't see the site without ?COLLCC=   ?
If so seach if in one of the active plugins or even in the theme you find something like wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( 'COLLCC','' ) or wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'COLLCC','' ).
Something that you probably could do is to detect what plugin is causing the issue, just deactivating all the plugins and then reactivating them until you have again the issue. If you don't find it switch to the default WordPress theme to see if it's the theme itself. Once you have found the plugin or theme, I would search or the code written above